# Average tries needed to find the right box (Amount of boxes declining)

Tags: probability

Let's say I have 10 boxes, and one of them contains an apple. I open one of them at a time, looking for the apple. Each time there will be one less box to open (And thus a higher chance of opening the right one), how many tries will it take on average to find the apple?

I've dabbled with this for a while, and I've come up with a few possible answers, although none of them seems 'right'.

Will it one average just be 5 tries, so when I've tried half the boxes, I would probably have found it?

Will it be around 6 tries, because at the first attempt the chance is 1/10, the next time it's 1/9, and if you keep going like that, and add the chances together, then at the 6th try, the chance will be just over 100% (109.5%).

I feel like there might be an easy answer, but for the life of me, I cannot figure it out.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hint: The probability that you'll find the apple on the $i$th try is the same for each $i=1,2,3,\dots,10$. That often seems counter-intuitive to people new to studying probability.

Comment: Is that true, even if you remove a box every time you've opened it? The second time you open a box, there are literally only 9 possible boxes, because one has been ruled out. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Yes, but the probability that you even open a second box is $\frac{9}{10}$, because $\frac{1}{10}$ times, you got it right the first time. So the probability that you will get the apple in your second try if $\frac{9}{10}\cdot \frac{1}{9}=\frac{1}{10}.$

Comment: Or consider it this way. You pick a strategy (an order to open the boxes) and another person independently picks where to put the apple. What is the probability she picked the first box in your strategy? Your second box?  Your third box? She picks them equally likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability argument might go:

If $T_n$ is the time, starting with $n$ boxes, then the expected (or average) value of $T_n$ is:

$$E(T_n)=1+\frac{n-1}{n}E(T_{n-1}), E(T_1)=1\tag{1}$$

This can be written as: "It requires one box, and, with probability $1-\frac{1}{n}=\frac{n-1}{n},$ we are left with the time for game $T_{n-1}.$"

So $$\begin{align}E(T_n)&=1+\frac{n-1}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-2}{n-1}+\cdots\\&=1 + \frac{n-1}{n}+\frac{n-2}n+\cdots +\frac{1}{n}\\&=\frac{n+1}{2}
\end{align} \tag{2}$$

You you don't like the hand-waving, you can prove $(2)$ from $(1)$ by induction.

Basically, the probability that you will pick the box at the $k$th opening is $\frac{1}{n}$ for all $k=1,\dots,n.$ That is sometimes counter-intuitive to beginning probability students, but is true.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this. The explanation seems to be absolutely brilliant and very thorough, so it's really just a result of my lacking math skills. But, essentially, the average required tries is the number of boxes, plus one divided by two? So for 10 boxes it would be 5,5?

Comment: Since each box is equally likely, you can consider it the average of the set of values $1,2,3,\dots,n$, which is $\frac{n+1}{2}.$ And yes, you should get $5.5$ when $n=10.$

Comment: But how is 5.5 the average of 10? I know that that's the result you get from the formula, but it just seems strange to me. I simulated this scenario in a program I wrote, and the average of 100,000 simulations were just about 5.5, so it's definitely correct, but it just seems strange to me.

Comment: If you roll a fair die (with values from $1$ to $6$) what is your average value? Do you think it is $3$?

Comment: "The average of $10$" doesn't make sense....

Comment: What is the average of $1$ and $2$? Of $1,2,3,4?$

Comment: That is very interesting. I think I get it now :) Thank you so much for your time and your patience.

Comment: It is a very common stumbling block when learning about probability. I've seen it often here, and remember making the mistake myself.